# Issues appending to a list in python

Tags: python, data-science

I have the following data file.

```
>| --- | | Adelaide | | --- | |  2021 | | --- | | Rnd | T | Opponent | Scoring | F | Scoring | A | R | M | W-D-L | Venue | Crowd |
> Date | | R1 | H | Geelong | 4.4 11.7 13.9 15.13  | 103 | 2.3 5.5 10.8
> 13.13  | 91 | W | 12 | 1-0-0 | Adelaide Oval |  26985 | Sat 20-Mar-2021 4:05 PM | | R2 | A | Sydney | 3.2 4.6 6.14 11.22  | 88 |
> 4.1 9.6 15.11 18.13  | 121 | L | -33 | 1-0-1 | S.C.G. |  23946 | Sat 27-Mar-2021 1:45 PM |
```

I created a code to manipulate that data to my desired results which is a list. When I print my variable row at the current spot it prints correctly.
However, when I append my list row to another list my_array I have issues. I get an empty list returned.
I think the issue is the placement of where I am appending?
My code is this:

```
with open('adelaide.md', 'r') as f:
    my_array = []
    team = ''
    year = ''
    for line in f:
        row=[]
        line = line.strip()
        fields = line.split('|')
        num_fields = len(fields)
        if len(fields) == 3:
            val = fields[1].strip()
        if val.isnumeric():
            year = val
        elif val != '---':
            team = val   
        elif num_fields == 15:
            row.append(team)
            row.append(year)
            for i in range(1, 14):
                row.append(fields[i].strip())
            print(row)
    my_array.append(row)
```

Comment: should `my_array.append(row)` be inside the for-loop?

Comment: You reset row to an empty list at the beginning of each line, resetting it.

Comment: I did and it doesn't work gives me a different output

Comment: You're making a lot of mistakes here. For example, you only set a value for `year` or `team` when `num_fields` is 3 (and then you only set one fo them, based on `fields[1]`), but you use those values when `num_fields` is 15. Also none of the lines in the sample data you supplied have either 3 or 15 fields. I can only recommend that you start over, and proceed step by step (e.g. first step, make a loop to print each line as you read it, next split and print each field, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

You need to append the row array inside the for loop.

Comment: I tried it. Still getting different output.

Comment: What is the output?

Answer (score 0):

I think last line should be inside the for loop. Your code is probably appending the last 'row' list. Just give it a tab.

Comment: It produces a different output.